# run app automatically upon reboot

Tags: scheduled-tasks

My XP PC runs a scheduled task to reboot automatically every night (shutdown.exe). I need a specific app to startup automatically upon reboot. My problem is that the app doesn’t start until I type the Windows password into the Windows login screen. Please advise what I can do in order to solve this problem, so that the app starts automatically upon reboot or suggest a way for my PC to log into Windows automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it as a service

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Run it as a script

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/gptext_assigncomputerstartupscripts.mspx?mfr=true

or you make it so you automatically log in

Run Prompt -> control userpasswords2 -> un-check users must enter a user name... -> click apply -> enter credentials -> click ok

Answer (score 4):

You have a very fast and well described method [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/learnmore/tips/knox2.mspx) without using additional software.

Edit: Wrapped up method: (works for windows xp, vista and 7)

- Click Start, click Run, and type `control userpasswords2`
- Uncheck

  > Users must enter a username and
  >   password to use this computer
- Click apply
- Enter the user name and password you wish to automatically log on with, and then click OK / OK.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If none of those methods work for you then you might like to look at TweakUI, part of the XP [Power Toys](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) from Microsoft.  That allows you to set up auto-login credentials so the machine automatically logs in at reboot.